# boton de guardar

Tags: java, java-swing

el profesor lo que quiere es esto,yo hice todo mi formulario con codigo incluyendo la tabla,todo lo puse en un JPanel con todo me refiero a los componentes,ya sea botones,textos,cajas de texto mas la tabla, pero necesito que me ayuden con e boton de guardar ya que e provado varios metodos y no me funcionan inclusive probe crear una clase aparte para crear un constructor  pero no comprendo el por que no me funciona,esta pagina no me deja colorcar todo el codigo como para que lo usen en netbeans 8.1 y visialicen lo que hice ;( espero me entiendan

Botón Guardar:
Deben mostrar un mensaje de información donde solicite si desea guardar la información (Si o NO).
De seleccionar la opción SI
Debe colocar todos los parámetros en vacío o sin opción seleccionada.
Y mostrar un mensaje de confirmación que los datos fueron almacenados (el almacenado será solo simulado)
De seleccionar NO
Debe dejar todo con los datos llenados o seleccionados

```
private void guardar(){
JButton boton1 = new JButton();
boton1.setText("Guardar");
boton1.setBounds(100,300,100,40);
panel.add(boton1);




ActionListener oyentedeaccion2 = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"desea guardar?");


}};
boton1.addActionListener(oyentedeaccion2);
}
```

Comment: buenas! lo que no te funciona es el popup de confirmación o no se ejecuta el codigo dentro del actionPerformed directamente?

Comment: fijate si por casualidad no te está quedando detrás del frame/panel actual y no estás viendo el dialogo. Puedes probar lo siguiente para descartar eso: final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);    
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "Here I am");

Comment: hola amigo,muchas gracias por tu aporte, lo que sucede es que para agregar el contenido de unas cajas de texto en una tabla debo crear constructores y algunas cosas mas que se me esta hacindo complicado por el simple hecho de que tengo todos los componentes en un JPanel

Comment: la verdad no  me queda claro si el botón guardar se ejecuta y no funciona, no se ejecuta o ahora sí funciona. Respecto a tu comentario, intenta separar el problema y simplificar el jpanel. Tal vez crear otro para la tabla y no tener uno solo con todos los componentes.

Answer (score 0):

Diría que tu problema está a  la hora de añadir el ActionListener al boton de guardar, que entiendo es tu boton1, tienes que declararlo como `boton1.addActionListener(new oyentedeaccion2);` No se como te lo habrá explicado tu profesor pero generalmente los ActionListener se declaran como la implementación de una clase, así que tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
class oyentedeaccion2 implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"desea guardar?");
    }
}
```

Esta manera de crear una jav class es muy util ya que la puedes meter el codigo dentro de otra java class.